# Efficiency in this mini vb school project?

Tags: vb.net

We had to make a quick project in an hour so I made a small password analyser. Are there any obvious inefficiencies or errors? Regards, Ryan.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Public Class passwordAnalysis

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSubmit.Click
    If chkTsCs.Checked = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("We cannot procede to analyse your password without prior permission. Please agree to the Ts and Cs.")
    Else
        If Len(txtPassword.Text) < 7 Then
            txtPassword.BackColor = Color.Red
            MessageBox.Show("Your password contains fewer than 7 characters, making it incredibly weak. As a result, your online security may be compromised. We suggest you add more characters to your password and change it immediately.")
        Else
            If Regex.IsMatch(txtPassword.Text, "^[a-zA-Z]*$") Then
                txtPassword.BackColor = Color.Orange
                MessageBox.Show("Whilst you do have more than 7 characters, you could add a number to ensure maximum strength for your password")
            Else
                txtPassword.BackColor = Color.Green
                MessageBox.Show("What a strong password! You have at least 7 characters and a number.")
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: How is a question off-topic?

Comment: From the help page [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual **problems** that you face." Your question is not a *problem*, it's a *Code Review*

Comment: Ahh, sorry I didn't realize! Thanks.

Comment: No problem, we're all here to learn, except [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) our loved master.

Comment: Would you by any chance know how to check if a dictionary word is present in a part of their password? Even if it was 'fgjdcheesekgfk' - regardless of the fact it's contained in other text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few points:

1. `and a number` => no, it can be any special char also, like `?&é"'(-è_çà)`
2. the password can be `aaaaaaa` which is far from safe :)
3. `chkTsCs.Checked = False` => you assign `False` to `chkTsCs.Checked` => just check with `!chkTsCs.Checked`